# "Conditional condition" in quadratic optimization

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem on the form

$$
  min_x x^{\top}Cx 
$$

Subject to

$$
  \mu^{\top}x \geq r
$$
$$
  x_j\geq0
$$
$$
  0.75 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \leq 1
$$

So far, I know what to do and how to do it. However, I want to extend the conditions with a condition of "if $x_j > 0$ then $x_j \geq v_j$". I.e., $x_j$ can be zero, but if it is not it must be greater than some other constant. Is this possible to express in the matrix form of the standard QP such that it can be used as a parameter of MatLabs *quadprog* or Rs *solve.QP*, and, if so, how would one go about doing it?

Comment: What is $v_j$ in the context of the problem?

Comment: @Paul, it is a constant related to the underlying variables. Every row/column of C has a related $\mu_j$ and $v_j$ that are constant.

Comment: Practically speaking, say you want to minimize the cost of purchasing fruit. However, if you buy bananas you have to buy at least, say, 1.5 bananas (assuming one can buy parts of fruits).

Comment: The resulting problem will be non convex so I suspect that might limit your options with Qp solvers. Other than adding $x_k \ge v_k$ or $x_k \le 0$ sort of constraints nothing obvious leaps out to me.

Comment: Sure, you can phrase it as a mixed-integer quadratic problem by adding a constraint $v_jz\leq x_j\leq Mz$ for a suitably big $M$, where $z$ is a binary variable. This is sometimes called a semi-continuous variable by some solvers. https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#semi-continuous-variables Then you need a solver capable of mixed-integer QP.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek, I see. I'm afraid I've already rephrased my problem to avoid the issue, but I will look into this for future reference. Thank you!